# How do I install libosip 2.2.3 and libexosip 2.2.3 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

I am unable to install  libosip 2.2.3 and libexosip 2.2.3 in Ubuntu 14.04.

I can't find exactly these packages, so I can't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search in the Ubuntu Software Center for:

- Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) library
- EXtended osip library

These packages are available to install from the Ubuntu Software Center. Unfortunately the version numbers of the packages aren't exactly 2.2.3 as you asked for. In fact, the packages are much more recent than that.

You can also download the packages manually and [install the .tar.gz files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file):

- [libosip2-2.2.2.tar.gz](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/osip/) 24-Nov-2005
- [libeXosip2-2.2.3.tar.gz](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/exosip/) 18-Apr-2006

Be aware of the risk of damaging your operating system. It's been a long time since these packages were released, so there will probably be installation issues with unmet dependencies. It would make sense to try installing these packages on a virtual machine first to avoid breaking your current Ubuntu installation.

Comment: So many thank for your answer.

Libosip 2.2.2 installed without error.

But when i doing ./configure, Libexosip prompt a line : configure: error: oRTP library not installed. Please install or use --disable-josua

==>> so i cant find this package.

I'm doing a project about IMS-IPTV. Due to lack of experience, i cant find out this oRTP library.

Please help me. So many thank from Viet Nam.

Comment: There is a package in the Ubuntu Software Center called Real-time Transport Protocol stack (libortp). This is the ortp library. You could try installing the correct package for your OS's architecture and then check whether it solves your problem or maybe you'll get a different error message that says: `configure: error: Couldn't find ortp library` which might mean that it is looking for a different version of the libortp package depending on whatever else that the error message says. If so, you could try searching for the correct version of libortp and install it manually.

Comment: You can also download the ortp package manually from [this webpage](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/linphone/ortp/sources/) and install the .tar.gz file. There are 16 different versions of ortp available from ortp-0.9.1.tar.gz 22-Sep-2006 to ortp-0.23.0.tar.gz 20-Feb-2014.